# Vue.js environment configuration

Tags: vue.js, npm, build, configuration

I wan't to create a client application using Vue.js. Currently I'm facing the question: How do I get the address of my backend service?

I have a primary constraints to the solution that is supposed to answer that question: The final client artifact (the result of the build process, "vue-cli-service build") must be environment independent. This is important! That means that absolutely no environment specific information are supposed to be built-in. If the address of my backend service changes, it MUST NOT be necessary to build a new client artifact. It MUST be possible to just reconfigure the production environment and reuse the current client artifact.

My approach is to add an additional configuration file that is delivered by the same web server that also delivers my Vue.js client: a /configuration.json or something like that. This configuration file can contain the information I need. This approach can be split into 3 sub-tasks:
(a) Add functionality to the Vue.js client to read the configuration.json from the web server (that also delivers the client). This should be easy.
(b) Find a way to let the production web server deliver this configuration.json. I already have some ideas for that.
(c) Find a way to let the local development server deliver the additional configuration.json.

My biggest problem is (c) right now. I don't know how to configure the local development server, which is started by "vue-cli-service serve".

Any ideas how to solve (c)? Maybe you also know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I just give the following answer to another question, but it might apply to your question as well. If you need to load specific presets from a JSON file. How to produce that JSON file is a separate question I guess.

> I’ve had a similar case once with the need to adjust some presets
>   without rebuilding the project every time. I ended up moving the Vue
>   object that rendered the app inside an async Axios function. Of course
>   it affects loading time, since it waits for the JSON file to be
>   loaded, in my case this was less important. This is a summary of such
>   a setup.

```
axios.get('./config.json')
.then(function(response) {
    let config = response.data
    //commit data to vuex store for example

    new Vue({
        store,
        render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error)
})
```